# How to debug a stack overflow error in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, stack-overflow

In my application, I am getting following error in IE8 (IE7 standards document mode)

It says

```
SCRIPT2343: Stack overflow at line: 1 
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space 
jquery-min.js, line 1 character 30159
```

I do not get these errors in Firefox and Chrome.

Since my application code is quite huge, I am unable to understand how do I debug exactly in IE. Is the jquery-min.js that IE is saying the actual cause OR that might not necessarily be the issue?

Can I use the Developer toolbar to somehow debug this stack overflow issue? Or is there another way to debug?

Comment: Did your code uses bootbox.js library ?

Comment: No..it uses bootstrap.js...

Comment: I came across the same situation and got stuck for days with it. I had this problem while calling model pop ups. During my long search I've seen a bug registered for JQuery-UI plugin with same characteristics.Mine got fixed by taking latest version of Jquery-ui and bootbox.js(which is someway derived from bootstrap)- I am not sure whether it is your problem.

Comment: It might be the issue...but like I said...i have no clue where the problem lies...the only clue that I have now...is I get the error once the modal div (which uses bootstrap) is loaded...and i also get to see the same stack overflow error when I click anywhere on the page...So does that mean the issue might be related to a click event  (once the modal div has loaded)?

Comment: That was the behavior i had. But I had the issue mainly while using modal confirmation. I think the issues are related and taking the latest of bootstrap will resolve the issue.

Comment: Hmm...So you also faced the issues on IE8...and fixed "just" by using the latest bootstrap js...Is there some kind of a known issue with bootstrap ?

Comment: For now, can I just use the latest code only for bootstrap-modal.js

Comment: Actually i saw a bug filed in Jquery-UI. But when i debugged i find even if the error occur in JQuery library the the last traceable function call is from bootstrap. so just did a replacement with latest bootstrap library and issue got fixed.(Without changing not even one line of code). You can use visual studio or IE's built in tool to debug the scripts in IE. Just enable debugging.

Comment: Could you please help me more with IE debugging..i m comfortable with using Firebug..but do not have much exp of using IE Debugging...basically is there some way by which I can trace function calls....know where exactly is the code failing...

Comment: Yes of course you can debug scripts in IE like Firebug (but not as easy as in firebug). Check the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can debug script in IE using IE developer tools**. Just **press F12 to activate developer tools**. IE also comes with an in built developer tool like Google chrome(not not that user friendly). But you can still use it to debug script and to watch call stack. use `debugger;` like we use in other debuggers.

You can get better control in script debugging using visual studio. If you a .Net developer you can use VS itself to debug JavaScript.

[Find more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thx a lot for that...Just one questions..You said "use debugger; like we use in other debuggers."...Could you please elaborate on how that can be used

Comment: if you use line `debugger;` inside the script code. The browser developer tool will pause the script in that location allowing us to debug the values and call stack at that time and we can perform line by line code execution. I assumed that you are familiar with that since you said earlier that you use firebug for script debugging.

Comment: Yes, I have used Firebug in the past...But I add breakpoints in the code while doing firebug debugging....so i assume this is similar to doing that...

Comment: Yes similar to that. But here we add break points while we code. That's the only difference.

Comment: Oh cool...Thx for that info and also for the OUTSTANDING help with the bootstrap issue...My actual cause for the stack overflow error now seems to be with the bootstrap js (enforceFocus method specifically)...Thx again...